# Can I swap variables inside a function using pointers in R?

Tags: r, function, pointers, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference

Here is a silly (maybe only in my mind) way to accomplish my goal:

```
A <- "This is a test."
B <- "This is the answer."
swap <- function(item1,item2) {
  tmp   <- item2
  item2 <- item1
  item1 <- tmp
  return(list(item1,item2))
}
AB <- swap(A,B)
A <- AB[[1]]
B <- AB[[2]]
```

But I'm considering something similar to the C code following:

```
void swap(int *a, int *b)
{
    int iTemp ;
    iTemp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = iTemp;

}
```

My motivations:

- My real data is quite large, e.g. 5k*5k matrix, so the assignment of the existing variable in the iteration twice, inside the function and outside the function, must be time squandering.
- The closest question on the SO is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29870960/access-object-by-address-pointer), but just like the OP in the question, my R session also has lots of objects: I'm working with `Rmpi`, and each slave will have a great number of variables.
- In my humble opinion, `R` is written in `C`, so `R` may have pointers like `C` does, while I can't find much on the net surprisingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this; this just assigns to the parent environment.

```
A <- "This is a test."
B <- "This is the answer."

swap <- function(item1, item2) {
  tmp <- item1
  assign(deparse(substitute(item1)), item2, pos = 1)
  assign(deparse(substitute(item2)), tmp, pos = 1)
}

swap(A, B)
A
#[1] "This is the answer."
B
#[1] "This is a test.
```

Comment: wow, thanks! This is a nice method which must optimize my existing code.

Comment: @HunterJiang But please read [Why is using assign bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17559390/why-is-using-assign-bad)! I think the use of `assign` should be actively discouraged/avoided, especially if you're new to R.

Comment: @MauritsEvers What an interesting and helpful link! Thanks for your warmly advise.

Comment: @HunterJiang You're very welcome. The [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17559390/why-is-using-assign-bad) includes posts by some of the most knowledgeable people from the R community, so definitely worth a read;-)